# Get a single word before or after another word

Tags: php, regex, text, matching

How can I get a single word before or after another word in a given text.
For example :

```
Text = "This is Team One Name"
```

and what if there is no word but digites before the middle word for example

```
Text= "This is 100 one Name"
```

How can I get the  `100` ?

How Can I get the word before and after `One`, being `Team` and `Name`? Any regex pattern matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function get_pre_and_post($needle, $haystack, $separator = " ") {
    $words = explode($separator, $haystack);
    $key = array_search($needle, $words);
    if ($key !== false) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            return $words[1];
        }
        else if ($key == (count($words) - 1)) {
            return $words[$key - 1];
        }
        else {
            return array($words[$key - 1], $words[$key + 1]);
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

$sentence  = "This is Team One Name";
$pre_and_post_array = get_pre_and_post("One", $sentence);
```

Comment: @DavidBélanger I was hoping someone would notice that :)

Comment: Perfect ! worked smoothly with php and should be convertable easily to other languages, very nice code, not using regex, which saves a bit of a headache !

Comment: As I could notice, it is also flexible to match if the 'one' is at the beginning and at the end of the text. However it should return an array even if it's the case with a null, where before or after doesn apply.

Answer (score 5):

By capturing them into [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
(?:(?<firstWord>\w+)\s+|^)middleWord(?:\s+(?<secondWord>\w+)|$)
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice regex solution, however it's a big of headache working with groups. But truly its a great patter !

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$Text = "This is Team One Name";
$Word = 'Team';
preg_match('#([^ ]+\s+)' . preg_quote($Word) . '(\s[^ ]+)#i', $Text, $Match);
print_r($Match);
```

Comment: You forgot to match the spaces around `$Word`. Also `U` is going to screw up your results (there will only ever be one character in the second word). Just leave it out. It's confusing anyway. If you want ungreediness, use `+?` (but as I said, you don't even want ungreediness here)